# Using Cauchy integral formula with real constants powers

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

How can I use Cauchy integral formula to calculate the following integral

$\int_{\partial \mathbb{D}} \dfrac{f(z)}{z^n}dz$

where $f $ is entire, $\mathbb{D}$ denotes the unit disc, and $n \geq 1$ is a real constant.

Can I use the Cauchy integral Formula - Higher derivatives version with $\Gamma(n)$ instead of $n!$ ?

Comment: $z^n$ is not continuous on the unit circle unless $n$ is an integer so the integral in question depends on how you cut it to make sense of $z^n$ so no unique answer; try and work out an easy case like $n=3/2, f=1$

Comment: @Conrad, So, we can't use Cauchy integral formula at all.

Comment: Only for $n$ integer

Comment: If $n$ is a fraction greater than $1$ then you would have a branch point at the origin, so $n$ has to be an integer to use Cauchy's Integral Formula.